# How to make the text of a Label change automatically?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, tkinter, combobox

I am having issues with updating `ttk.Label(frame, text=value).grid(column=1, row=2)` automatically when a new `Combobox` option is selected. I know it has something to do with my handler function, but for the life of me, I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from time import *

vegetable_needs = {
    'Tomato': {'ph': '6', 'moisture': '60', 'humidity': '70'},
    'Bell pepper': {'ph': '9', 'moisture': '61', 'humidity': '71'},
    'Cucumber': {'ph': '2', 'moisture': '62', 'humidity': '72'},
    'Broccoli': {'ph': '4', 'moisture': '63', 'humidity': '73'},
    'Green Bean': {'ph': '1', 'moisture': '64', 'humidity': '74'},
    'Zucchini': {'ph': '5', 'moisture': '65', 'humidity': '75'},
    'Sweet potatoe': {'ph': '0', 'moisture': '66', 'humidity': '76'}
}

#Create Frame
def create_input_frame(container):
    #declare string variables
    vegetable = tk.StringVar()

    frame = tk.Frame(container, borderwidth=1, relief=RIDGE, padx=15, pady=10)
    
    options = ttk.Combobox(frame, width = 20, textvariable = vegetable)
    #list of veggies
    options['values'] = (
    "Tomato",
    "Bell pepper",
    "Cucumber",
    "Broccoli",
    "Green Bean",
    "Zucchini",
    "Sweet potatoe"
    )
    options['state'] = 'readonly'

    ttk.Label(frame, text = "Select a veggie: ", font = ("Times New Roman", 10)).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=0)
    options.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    options.current()
    

    def handler(event):
        current = options.current()
        if current != -1:
            ph_level = vegetable_needs[vegetable.get()]['ph']
            value = ph_level
            print(value)
    
    
    options.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', handler)
    
    ttk.Label(frame, text=value).grid(column=1, row=2)
    ttk.Label(frame, text='PH Level').grid(column=0, row=2)
  
    return frame

#Create the main window
def create_main_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Growing Veggies')
    root.attributes('-toolwindow', False)
    r1=0
    r2=0
    r3=0
    
    #Create zones 1-5 row 0
    if number_of_zones >= 1 and number_of_zones <= 5:
        for r1 in range(number_of_zones):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
    #Create zones 6-10 rows 0-1
    elif number_of_zones > 5 and number_of_zones <=10:
        for r1 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
        for r2 in range(number_of_zones - 5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=1)
            r2+=1
    #Create zones 11-15 rows 0-2
    elif number_of_zones > 10 and number_of_zones <=15:
        for r1 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
        for r2 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=1)
            r2+=1
        for r2 in range(number_of_zones - 10):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=2)
            r3+=1

    #Output an error
    else:
        root.title('ERROR')
        ttk.Label(root, text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 15").grid(column=1, row=1, padx=15, pady=5)
        ttk.Button(root, text = "Acknowledge", command=quit).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    value = "?"
    number_of_zones = int(input("How many zones should be made? "))
    create_main_window()
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create variables to reference your labels by. Also, you need to update them when the PH is changed. Here is what the code should look like, with changes marked with `### EDITED LINE` and `### ADDED LINE`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

vegetable_needs = {
    'Tomato': {'ph': '6', 'moisture': '60', 'humidity': '70'},
    'Bell pepper': {'ph': '9', 'moisture': '61', 'humidity': '71'},
    'Cucumber': {'ph': '2', 'moisture': '62', 'humidity': '72'},
    'Broccoli': {'ph': '4', 'moisture': '63', 'humidity': '73'},
    'Green Bean': {'ph': '1', 'moisture': '64', 'humidity': '74'},
    'Zucchini': {'ph': '5', 'moisture': '65', 'humidity': '75'},
    'Sweet potatoe': {'ph': '0', 'moisture': '66', 'humidity': '76'}
}

#Create Frame
def create_input_frame(container):
    #declare string variables
    vegetable = tk.StringVar()

    frame = tk.Frame(container, borderwidth=1, relief=RIDGE, padx=15, pady=10)
    
    options = ttk.Combobox(frame, width = 20, textvariable = vegetable)
    #list of veggies
    options['values'] = (
    "Tomato",
    "Bell pepper",
    "Cucumber",
    "Broccoli",
    "Green Bean",
    "Zucchini",
    "Sweet potatoe"
    )
    options['state'] = 'readonly'

    veggie_label = ttk.Label(frame, text = "Select a veggie: ", font = ("Times New Roman", 10)) ### EDITED LINE
    veggie_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=0) ### ADDED LINE
    options.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    options.current()
    

    def handler(event):
        current = options.current()
        if current != -1:
            ph_level = vegetable_needs[vegetable.get()]['ph']
            value = ph_level
            value_label.config(text=value) ### ADDED LINE
            print(value)
    
    
    options.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', handler)
    
    value_label = ttk.Label(frame, text=value) ### EDITED LINE
    value_label.grid(column=1, row=2) ### ADDED LINE
    ph_label = ttk.Label(frame, text='PH Level') ### EDITED LINE
    ph_label.grid(column=0, row=2) ### ADDED LINE
    
    return frame

#Create the main window
def create_main_window():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Growing Veggies')
    # root.attributes('-toolwindow', False)
    r1=0
    r2=0
    r3=0
    
    #Create zones 1-5 row 0
    if number_of_zones >= 1 and number_of_zones <= 5:
        for r1 in range(number_of_zones):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
    #Create zones 6-10 rows 0-1
    elif number_of_zones > 5 and number_of_zones <=10:
        for r1 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
        for r2 in range(number_of_zones - 5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=1)
            r2+=1
    #Create zones 11-15 rows 0-2
    elif number_of_zones > 10 and number_of_zones <=15:
        for r1 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r1, row=0)
            r1+=1
        for r2 in range(5):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=1)
            r2+=1
        for r2 in range(number_of_zones - 10):
            input_frame = create_input_frame(root)
            input_frame.grid(column=r2, row=2)
            r3+=1

    #Output an error
    else:
        root.title('ERROR')
        error_label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Please enter a valid number between 1 and 15")
        error_label.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=15, pady=5)
        ttk.Button(root, text = "Acknowledge", command=quit).grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    value = "?"
    number_of_zones = int(input("How many zones should be made? "))
    create_main_window()
```

Notice I define the labels as variables: `value_label`, `ph_label`, and `error_label`. This enables the labels to be referenced throughout the program. Also notice how in the `handler` function, I call `value_label.config(text=value)`. This sets the value_label's text to the PH level.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense. I knew I was missing something like that, but couldn't figure it out no matter what I tried. I appreciate it

Comment: Just remember to do that in the future. It can save a lot of trouble! Happy coding!

Comment: @SamMatzko Your answer is right, but you should avoid importing everything from a module. Also, you imported ```tkinter``` twice. This is just a suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: @IshaanJog Thanks! You're right. I corrected the imports. Hopefully `from tkinter.constants import *` is better than `from tkinter import *`. I could alternately use `from tkinter import constants`, and just reference the constants accordingly. Also, `time` was imported when it didn't need to be, so I removed that too.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just use the `textvariable=` option instead of the `text=` one when creating the `ttk.Label` and then the `Label` will update automatically everytime the `vegtable` `StringVar`'s value is changed.

```
#    ttk.Label(frame, text=value).grid(column=1, row=2)
    ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=vegetable).grid(column=1, row=2)
    ttk.Label(frame, text='PH Level').grid(column=0, row=2)
```